# Changing edge attributes in networkx multigraph

Tags: python, networkx

In a multigraph each call to *add_edge(a,b,weight=1)* will add a new edge between nodes *a* and *b*. When building the graph, is it possible to modify this weight when *a* and *b* are found again. Right now I make a check to find whether (a, b) or (b, a) are connected, then have to *delete* the edge, and *add* a new one. It seems to me that I should simply be able to update the weight.

Note: I do need multigraphs because I use different types of edges between nodes (differentiated using *key*)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Multigraph.add_edge](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.MultiGraph.add_edge.html) documentation indicates that you should use the `key` argument to uniquely identify edges in a multigraph. Here's an example:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.MultiGraph()
>>> G.add_edge(1, 2, key='xyz', weight=2)
>>> G.add_edge(1, 2, key='abc', weight=1)
>>> G.edges(data=True)
[(1, 2, {'weight': 2}), (1, 2, {'weight': 1})]
```

Now, to update the edge keyed by `xyz`, just pass that parameter in again:

```
>>> G.add_edge(1, 2, key='xyz', weight=7)
>>> G.edges(data=True)
[(1, 2, {'weight': 7}), (1, 2, {'weight': 1})]
```

To read the previous value, you can use [get_edge_data](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.MultiGraph.get_edge_data.html#networkx.MultiGraph.get_edge_data) like this:

```
>>> G.get_edge_data(1, 2, key='xyz')
{'weight': 7}
```

Comment: Thanks! how do I retrieve the edges that correspond to the key? to know the previous value of _weight_ for example. Do I have to loop through all the edges to check the key first?

Comment: excuse me, but are there any ways to draw multigraph? I tried it do so:  http://paste.org.ru/?o2jv6a  But only one connection between two nodes is drawn

Comment: You should ask that as a question. Off topic for this comment thread

Comment: @E6aTb_E6aTb , jterrace is right, but in any case see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17823100/1959808) and also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15069150/1959808).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to update the attributes of an edge (multigraph or not).

My preferred way is to access the edge of the graph as you would a dictionary.

```
for edge in graph.edges:
    # edge is a tuple of the edge definition (u, v, key)
    if key == value:
        graph[edge[0]][edge[1]][edge[2]]['weight'] = new_weight
```

So if you have the nodes of the edges and the key you can change the weight any time you want. If you don't have the key, you can loop though all the edges until you find the correct edge key combo to update.

You can also update all the edges in a graph using the `set_edge_attributes` function. You can find a good explanation of that in the [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_edge_attributes.html#set-edge-attributes). Note that this function's arguments have changed from v1.x to v2.x.

Comment: What do [0], [1] and [2] mean in: graph[edge[0]][edge[1]][edge[2]]   ?  Did you mean to use u, v and key?

Comment: @KevinP. you are correct. In the for loop, edge is actually a tuple of the information commonly identified as u, v, and key