# Number of edges differ when converting pandas dataframe to Networkx object

Tags: python, dataframe, networkx

I am using `networkx` to build an email network structure from a txt file where each row represents an "edge." I first loaded the txt file (3 columns: {'#Sender', 'Recipient', 'time'}) into Python and then converted to an `networkx` object using the following code:

```js
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
email_df = pd.read_csv('email_network.txt', delimiter = '->')
email = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(email_df, '#Sender', 'Recipient', edge_attr = 'time')
```

The `email.txt` data can be accessed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pywfs60y8nbyquw/email.txt?dl=0).

However, `email_df` (a `pandas` `DataFrame` object) has a length of 82927, while `email` (a `Networkx` object) has a length of 3251.

```
In [1]: len(email_df)
In [2]: 82927
In [3]: len(email.edges())
In [4]: 3251
```

I got really confused because even if for rows containing the same two nodes in the first two columns of `email_df` with the same sequence of direction (say, '1' to '2'), the third column ('time', meaning timestamped) should distinguish them from each other, hence, no replicated edges would appear. Then why does the number of edges dramatically decreased from 82927 to 3251 after I used `nx.from_pandas_dataframe` to read from `email_df'?

Would anyone help explain this to me?

Thank you.

Comment: Code windows are meant for JS code only. For all other languages, please paste your code, highlight it and hit ctrl+k to format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line here is saying to take the `Sender` column as the source node, the `Recipient` column as the Target and add the `time` as *edge attributes*. So you are only creating a single (directed) edge between Sender and Recipient, and only the time of the last row will be added as an attribute of the edge.

```
email = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(email_df, '#Sender', 'Recipient', edge_attr = 'time')
```

You can only have one edge defined for a pair of nodes - you could group the dataframe before constructing your network and use the count as the weights for the edges,

```
edge_groups = email_df.groupby(["#Sender", "Recipient"], as_index=False).count().rename(columns={"time":"weight"})
email = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(edge_groups, '#Sender', 'Recipient', edge_attr = 'weight')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your explanation of my code is correct, but I did not intend to include only the time of the last row as 'time' attribute between a given pair of Sender and Recipient as attribute. How can I recover those missing "edges"?

Comment: You can only have a single edge defined between a pair of nodes - I have added an example to my answer of one way you could incorporate the missing data.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, but Python still returned a length of 3251.

Comment: From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469515/changing-edge-attributes-in-networkx-multigraph), it seems that one needs to add a `key` to uniquely identify an edge between the same pair of nodes, but is there an alternative way to do this, especially for a large dataset? (I won't be able to add a unique key for each of the 82927 rows)